# Different replacements for different patterns in sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, text-editor

I need to replace two patterns in each line of a file. Lets say for example the file contains the following:

```
pattern1 a1 b1 c1
pattern2 a2 b2 c2
pattern1 a1 b1 c1
```

Basically, anywhere "pattern1" appears, a1 needs to replaced with a2 and b1 for b2, and so on. However, I also want to change pattern1 into pattern2.

So far I have something that comes kind of close:

```
/pattern1/ s/a1 b1 c1/a2 b2 c2/
```

**Note, I want to keep the entire sed script in a single file.**

**UPDATE**
Desired output, this may not be the best example, I'll answer any questions.

```
pattern2 a2 b2 c2
pattern2 a2 b2 c2
pattern2 a2 b2 c2
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what would be a valid output for any given input, could you post an example?

Comment: @heltonbiker Sorry about that, I updated the question.

Comment: You say 'a1 ... substituted for a2' (meaning replace occurrences of a2 by a1) but your example suggests 'a1 ... substituted by a2' (meaning replace occurrences of a1 by a2); which did you really want?

Comment: Why you got, on lines 1 and 3, different outputs for the same input?

Comment: @Jonathon Sorry, I guess I should proof-read my questions more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do it.

```
sed -e '/pattern1/{
        s/a2/a1/
        s/b2/b1/
        s/c2/c1/
        s/pattern1/pattern2/
        }' "$@"
```

You can often collapse that to a single line by using semi-colons in place of newlines (but some versions of `sed` are fussier about that than others).  The `-e` isn't strictly necessary in this context.

It isn't entirely clear from the question whether 'a1' should be replaced by 'a2' or vice versa; this code works off the wording "a1 needs to be substituted for a2" (meaning "replace occurrences of a2 with a1"), but the example suggests the opposite substitution.  If the other meaning is required, then use lines like `s/a1/a2/` instead of `s/a2/a1/`.

Comment: @Jonathon Thanks, you UNIX guys are quick to respond :)